# layout for htc sensation

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create layout that supports all screens

So, I added layouts folder like

layout-small

layout-large

layout-xlarge

layout-w600dp

and I edited all of them to be suitable

but when I run the app in HTC Sensation 2.1 they appear not in the right position

this is the code of layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
tools:context=".SebhaActivity"
android:background="#4b6702"
 >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/sebha_bg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zakr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/first_zekr"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/azkar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/Azkar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/karaza"
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/zakr"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_green"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="38dp" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the emulator shows it as what I want ..

[image: emulator]

but my mobile shows it as following..

[image: htc]

Any Help?

Comment: "it seems not fit"  ???

Comment: I mean that they are not in the right position in the htc, sorry for my English

Comment: Post some screenshots - what you want it to look like and what it actually does. You should consider using nested layouts, rather than trying to make it all work with one RelativeLayout, but without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's hard to give specific advice.

Comment: I added Screen Shots to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like a child view to show beneath another child view in a RelativeLayout, you should use specific constraints to that effect. So if you have one with id first_element and want something below that, you would do:
    android:layout_below="@id/first_element"

If you wanted an element along the bottom you can do:
    android:id="@+id/bottom_element"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

If you want an element above that:
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_element"

Right now you center one thing, but other things you set to have a certain bottom margin and size and things like that. But when the size of the screen changes, your elements no longer line up the way they do on a different size screen. The solution is to use constraints that specifically specify you want things placed in relation to each other.

You can see a tutorial here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html